# Sequence of sequences with increasing start in R

Tags: r, sequence

I am searching for a **simple and elegant** (*basic R functions, no for cyclus*) mechanism as `function(start:stop)` which would create, for example `function(2:5)` the following vector sequence:

```
c(2:5, 3:5, 4:5, 5:5)

2,3,4,5,3,4,5,4,5,5
```

I have tried to put this into the function `seq()`. Sadly, function `seq()` does not allow for vector in the argument: `from=...`.

Do you know some solution?

Thank you very much

Comment: You can use `unlist(sapply(2:5, \(x) x:5))`  Or `x1 <- 2:5 + rep(0:3, each = 4);x1[x1 <6]`

Comment: Thanks, this works. Nevertheless, is there a solution which does not create a list? Are lists computationally more demanding than working only with vectors? Perfect, the second solution works! Thank you!

Comment: `sequence(4:1, 2:5)`

Comment: Please note that `sequence` is a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rep`

```
x1 <- 2:5 + rep(0:3, each = 4)
x1[x1 <6]
```

Comment: Just for clarity, do you have an idea which of these options is more efficient (computationally) if made for general use "function(start,stop)"? In "unlist" case we work with lists and in "rep" case we omit elements from vector.

Comment: @Athaeneus If there are lots of elements, probably the `rep` would be faster compared to loop with `sapply`